# What is this barrel jack plug?

Tags: connector, identification, plug

It is from a German-made sewing machine pedal. It appears to be 2mm inner diameter, 5mm outer diameter on the metal but has a 6mm plastic molded ring on the end...maybe to assure it stays connected?  I would like to buy this jack and solder to a new wire, or find an affordable cable with this jack on one end to replace a damaged one. Any ideas?  I've not seen this jack before.

[image: photo of plug - plan view]

[image: photo of plug - end view]

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be a proprietary plug, so I don’t think it is easily found (though it may have been cloned by (or for) 3rd-party replacement pedal makers).

If you search for you’ll find replacement cables for about $17 USD. Foot Control Cord for Husqvarna/Viking, Pfaff # 4130215-01

Comment: Thanks.  I decided that was the best way and ordered the cable for $17 and will cut off the other end to get the bare wires needed to repair.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not hardcore into jacks, but seems like some sort of default DC input like [this little dude](https://www.robotics.org.za/JACK-2155-M). Check it's conductivity inside and outside, if you have access to the other end's terminals, google those and do some tests accordingly. Do you have a multimeter? (might be unnecessary, though).

Comment: Hi, your link is to a "normal" coaxial power plug. It doesn't have the unusual element of the plug in the question - that larger-than-normal plastic part near the tip.